# Best indexes for dealing with multiple common queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two common queries that are run against a particular table.  One query uses columns A and B in the where clause, the other query uses columns B and C.

What are the best indexes to put on the table to speed up the queries?  Do I create a single index on all three columns, A, B and C?  Or do I create two indexes, one on A & B and the other on B & C?  Or do I create three indexes, one on A, the second on B the third on C?

I'm not sure exactly how SQL Server uses indexes.  Can a single query use two separate indexes (eg one on column A and another on column B)?  Would SQL Server use an index that covers three columns (eg A, B and C) if the query where clause only references two of the columns (eg A and B)?

Comment: These are questions easily answered with *some* knowledge about indexes and the query optimizer. You are better off doing 1h of research and knowing the rules.

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved." - If this is why this question has been put on hold, I would say a minimal understanding of indexes is what they are good for, and the difference between clustered and non-clustered indexes.  I would not expect a minimal understanding to include index intersection (where I asked "Can a single query use two separate indexes").  There are references on the web but I was hoping to collect the information in one place as I've never seen a single article that covers all of this well.

Comment: The level of minimal understanding varies with the problem to be solved. Your question could only be answered with "a) it depends, b) here is a 1h lecture about indexes". a) is not helpful, b) is not realistic. Go through that lesson yourself and you'll be gaining an important skill-set. The fact that you can now talk about index intersection tells me that you are successful already. Good job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to "what is best" is, in this case, "it depends", as it depends on things like cardinality of data, volume of data, and data type, but it's easy to answer "what is worst?".

Don't create an index that uses A, B, and C.  The reason is that when you create an index that contains two columns, it is ordered by the first column, and then the second column.  This means that if you were to create a column on A, B, and C, but then queried just on B and C, it wouldn't perform well at all.  Similarly, if you were to create an index on B and C, it would be next to useless for a query that only queried column C.  If all of your queries fall into one of the two categories you described above, you most likely would get the best performance from creating index AB and index BC.  Otherwise, you should probably create three indexes for a single column each.

Comment: For anyone coming across this question: gfreeman answers the question about whether to create a single index on all three columns A, B, and C.  The other question, about whether a single query could use multiple indexes, is covered here: [Using Index Intersection to Boost SQL Server Performance](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2003/index-intersection/).  In short, it is possible for a query to use multiple indexes.  The technique is called index intersection.

Comment: That's a pretty clear summation and primer, but pretty out of date. Concepts are still valid, though. If you'd like a little more in depth answer, however, this is the place http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095.aspx